# How to persist core data in cloud without authentication

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, cloudkit

I am designing an app using `core data` which has a local `Cache`. I am thinking of using `CloudKit` for syncing it across multiple `iOS` devices. Since `CloudKit` is not for `persisting` data, I am pretty sure that if user loses their phone that data is gone forever. My app doesn't require any authentication so how do I save the data in cloud along with local `Cache` so that it can be sync across multiple `iOS` devices like `iPad` or `iWatch`

P.S. Is it possible to save user generated content `files` in `Documents` so that they can get backed up by `iCloud` automatically without using `CloudKit`?

Comment: user generated content could be stored in application document folder easily

Comment: so that means core data is enough for my app and I need not use CloudKit to sync it across multiple devices?

Comment: exactly , simply store data into coredata and then access it from different application

Comment: can you please elaborate what different application means, I am new to this iOS development

Comment: CloudKit can absolutely be used as the persistent "truth" store for data. Save/update your records in your container's private database (which is user-specific). Cache the data locally. Fetch changes to update your local store.

Comment: Exactly the info I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is backed up on iTunes and iCloud periodically, so if your user changes the device then they can restore the data from there.Yes it is possible to save user generated content files in Documents so that they can get backed up by iCloud automatically without using CloudKit

Answer (score 0):

As per your problem , Only creating `Coredata` enables you to manage data across different devices but two important question need to understand before this :

1. How can you preload existing data into the `SQLite database`?
2. How can you use an existing `SQLite` database in  `Xcode` project?

Here is one of hot favourite tutorial for managing this :

> https://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration

Comment: I like the article about migrating if there are changes in model and will use this when situation arises but my app is not completed yet and I am struck in dilemma about how to go ahead and continue my app when it comes to persistence and manage data between devices because my initial plan was to use Coredata and iCloud but iCloud is deprecated.

Comment: if you want to just storing data into database and whenever user download app then it gets synch then there are two option 1st is coredata otherwise webservice , choice is urs

Comment: I like to stick with coredata but can you please elaborate how coredata does this saving and syncing just to give me a brief idea so that I can go ahead with my app

Comment: I already provided you the link , you should go through this link and just try to make a demo , then you will get exact idea how it works . Nothing happens without trying , even experienced developer try to create demo and learn thing . so create a demo and if further question then ping me